# Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: xyz), but input would be ambiguou Aborting

Tags: ssh, fabric

```
fab -P -H xyz disable_puppet
```

I am getting the error as **Fatal error: One or more hosts failed while executing task 'disable_puppet'  Aborting.** while running the fab command in bastion server to disable puppet in xyz server.

Answer (score -1):

For every new session, you have to add the `*id_rsa` keys.

Just add the key by running the command **`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`** i.e. *ssh-add ~/path to your key.*

If getting error as ***Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.***
and that's because your ssh-agent is not running so to run the ssh-agent, just give the command `eval ssh-agent -s` and *`ssh-agent -s`* should be inside the backquote ( ***'*** ), located under the tilde ( **~** ), rather than the single quote ( **'** ).
It should work for ubuntu or mac that use zsh and for **bash** can run  **`exec ssh-agent bash`**

Then, just add the key **`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`** and your fabric command `fab -P -H xyz disable_puppet` should work.